# verify cert in golang

Tags: go, cryptography

I'm trying to read a jws sent by apple, in order to prove that the jws was sent by apple, I have four certificate, three in the header of the jws and one given by the apple website:

I compile codes that I found online and create this

here is the header of the jws

```
{
  "alg": "ES256",
  "x5c": [
    "MIIEMDCCA7agAwIBA...", // Cert in base64
    "MIIDFjCCApygAwIBA...", // Cert in base64
    "MIICQzCCAcmgAwIBA..."  // Cert in base64
  ]
}
```

this one was download on the website:

I tried to read them like this :

```
const APP_STORE_NOTIFICATION_ROOT_CERT = `
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICQzCCAcmgAwIBAg...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
`
func (j *JWSES256) Verify() error {
    // Get the full certificate chain
    rootCert, err := j.extractCertByIndex(2)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    intermediateCert, err := j.extractCertByIndex(1)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    roots := x509.NewCertPool()
    ok := roots.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(APP_STORE_NOTIFICATION_ROOT_CERT))
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("failed to parse root certificate")
    }

    intermediate := x509.NewCertPool()
    intermediate.AddCert(intermediateCert)

    opts := x509.VerifyOptions{
        Roots:         roots,
        Intermediates: intermediate,
    }
    t, err := rootCert.Verify(opts)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
// j.extractCertByIndex(index int) do something like this
// // x509.ParseCertificate(base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(jws.header.x5c[index]))
```

In fact I don't have a lots of knowledge in the certificate area and don't know what I'm doing. Could someone explain me if everything is alright or where is the error ?